The DAO in my Wallet
some 8 years ago I invested 4 ETH into the DAO. I have now 4 ETH The DAO Token in my Ethereum Wallet.
Any chance to get this money back ?

If you still have access to the wallet's private key, you can withdraw your ETH using the WithdrawDAO contract.
To do so you'll have to perform two steps, all of which you can easily do on Etherscan as long as you have Metamask set up:

Approve the WithdrawDAO to transfer your TheDAO tokens:

Read the balanceOf() method of the TheDAO contract with your address as the argument
Call the approve() method of the TheDAO contract with the spender being the address of the WithdrawDAO contract and the amount being your previously read balance


On the WithdrawDAO contract, call the withdraw() method. What this will do is:

Transfer all your tokens to the WithdrawDAO contract
Refund you the same amount in ETH to your address.



Note: under no circumstances should you transfer the tokens directly to the WithdrawDAO contract directly without calling the withdraw() method, doing so will lead to them being lost forever.

It depends on what the value of your DAO token is.
If the DAO tokens you hold are worth less than 4 ETH, then you can't get the money you invested back unless the DAO token increases in price.
